# Dataset definition for D3 pie

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Below is a simple D3 that loads 'dataset' array into d3 pie. Works fine. What I don't understand is why it doesn't work when I change metrics headers (like count2 instead of count). Where in the code is the piece that defines it?

I'm asking as I want to load other dataset with different header for metrics.

Thanks in advance!

```
//declare dataset
var dataset = [
  { label: 'Abulia', count: 10 },
  { label: 'Betelgeuse', count: 20 },
  { label: 'Cantaloupe', count: 30 },
  { label: 'Dijkstra', count: 160 }
];

//declare pie variables
var width = 360;
var height = 360;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

//load d3 color scheme
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);

//apply current development to <svg>
var svg = d3.select(this.domNode)
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +  ',' + (height / 2) + ')'); //apply transformation

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius);


var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
  .sort(null);

//create chart:
var path = svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return color(d.data.label);
  });
```

Comment: It's right there, in the `pie()` function: `.value(function(d) { return d.count; })`. If you want to use "count2", change it to: `.value(function(d) { return d.count2; })`.

Comment: Its Here var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
  .sort(null);

Comment: Perfect, thank you guys!